# Vertical scrollbar is not coming up in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, visual-studio-extensions

I am designing a visual studio extension in which I need a dock panel window. I am able to get this window using WPF. In this particular window I am displaying dynamic list of some strings which exceeds 100. To achieve this, I am using listbox in that window.

As this list contains more than 100 strings, all the strings are not visible. I should be able scroll the list vertically to access all the strings. But I am not getting a vertical scrollbar. I tried some things but they are not working. I am a newbie to this so, I am unable to figure out what to do. The code is as follows.

```
<UserControl d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">      
<Grid >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True"  >
        <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolWindowTextKey}}" Text="Available Projects"></TextBlock>

        <ListBox Name="AllProjects" TabIndex="0"  Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />           
    </StackPanel>
</Grid> </UserControl>
```

I did these things in xaml form only and nothing in back-end c# code. Could you guys please  tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this you will see the scrollbar

```
<Grid >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True"  >
        <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Available Projects"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox Name="AllProjects" TabIndex="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="100"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Just fix the height property to a constant.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I am able to see the scrollbar now.